# Программа игнорирует условие в else if

Tags: json, node.js

Никак не могу понять, почему программа не видит мое условие в else if. Вроде все данные у меня правильные, но почему-то программа просто игнорирует это. 
`user - это Nuber(args[1])`. Внесу для ясности: когда user равен например 2, то по какой-то причине программа выполняет условие в else if, хотя user будет равен одному из чисел, которые находятся в json файле. На выходе я получаю следующее:

```
users_obj:1
user:2
```

Вот собственно код:

```js
Array.prototype.containsObjectWithId = function(peer_id) {
  return !!this.filter(function(el) {
    return el.hasOwnProperty('peer_id') && el.peer_id === peer_id
  }).length;
};

let obj = {
  "peers": [{
    "peer_id": 2000000017,
    "users": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  }]
};
let user = 2;

if (obj.peers.containsObjectWithId(2000000017) === true) {
  for (let o = 0; o < obj.peers.length; o++) {
    for (let ou = 0; ou < obj.peers[o].users.length; ou++) {
      if (obj.peers[o].peer_id === 2000000017) {
        if (obj.peers[o].users[ou] === user) {
          console.log('i.vk.call')
          /* i.vk.call('messages.send', {
                      peer_id: 2000000017,
                      message: "Этот пользователь уже в черном списке!"
                    }
                    )*/
        } else if (obj.peers[o].users[ou] !== user) {
          console.log("users_obj:" + obj.peers[o].users[ou])
          console.log("user:" + user)
        }
      }
    }
  }
} else {}
```

Буду признателен, если сможете помочь с моей проблемой :)

Comment: Взял на себя смелость упростить Ваш код, убрав упоминания неопределенных в нем переменных.

Comment: Собственно, мне кажется, теперь (после замены вызова `i.vk.call` на вывод в консоль) должно стать очевиднее, в чем проблема. :)

Comment: К сожалению, нет, не помогло(
Теперь вывод у меня такой:

users_obj:1
user:2
i.vk.call

Comment: Именно. Смотрите: Вы перебираете весь массив `obj.peers[0].users`. Для первого элемента (`1`) отрабатывает условие `else if`, но цикл-то продолжает работу, и дальше берется следующий элемент (`2`), и срабатывает уже ветка с `i.vk.call`

Comment: Да, но только users - является вводным данным, которое надо проверить на то, совпадает ли оно с теми, которые находятся в json файле. Если же оно не совпало, то выполнить уже else if. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при users !== obj.peers[o].users[ou] выполнялось уже условие else if и не выполнялось условие if(obj.peers[o].users[ou] === user). А так, у меня выполняются оба эти условия, хотя user !== obj.peers[o].users[ou]

Comment: Замените внутренний цикл на `if (obj.peers[o].peer_id === 2000000017 && obj.peers[o].users.some(usr => usr == user)) { ...`

Comment: Спасибо огромное ♥
Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @LOVEC3327 отметьте тогда ответ как принятый (галочка слева от ответа)  ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> у меня выполняются оба эти условия,

Естественно они выполняются оба. В массиве два элемента, один равен данному числу, а другой - нет. Отделите поиск элемента от вывода данных.

```
var indexInUsers = null;
for (let ou = 0; ou < obj.peers[o].users.length; ou++) {
  if (obj.peers[o].peer_id === 2000000017) {
    if (obj.peers[o].users[ou] === user) {
      indexInUsers = ou;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (indexInUsers != null) {
    console.log('i.vk.call')
} else {
    console.log("user not found:" + user)
}
```